# How to do the curl of the product of a function and a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-fields, differential-operators

I have the following property which says:

$∇ × (f G) = ∇f × G + f (∇ × G)$

Where $f$ is a differentiable **function** in an open set $S$ on $\mathbb {R}^3$ , and $G$ is a $C^1$ class vector field on $S$

I can't wrap my mind around where should I start for proving it, since I don't know how to do, from the left side, the curl of a product of a given function and a vector field (the $f G$ part)

From the right side, I don't know what $∇f × G $ means , while I guess that $f (∇ × G)$ is the function of the curl of G

Any hints or even solutions are welcome. I'm a bit green on this...

**Solved**:

$∇f×G$=$(\frac{∂f}{∂x},\frac{∂f}{∂y},\frac{∂f}{∂z}) × (G_1,G_2, G_3)=(\frac{∂f}{∂y}G3-\frac{∂f}{∂z}G2,\frac{∂f}{∂z}G1-\frac{∂f}{∂x}G3,\frac{∂f}{∂x}G2-\frac{∂f}{∂y}G1)$   ,

$f(∇×G)=f((\frac{∂G3}{∂y}-\frac{∂G2}{∂z},\frac{∂G1}{∂z}-\frac{∂G3}{∂x},\frac{∂G2}{∂x}-\frac{∂G1}{∂y})$ ,  (which to be expanded, ending up with the equivalent of the above with $f$ and $G_x$ "switched")

and on the left side:

$∇×(fG)=(\frac{∂fG3}{∂y}-\frac{∂fG2}{∂z},\frac{∂fG1}{∂z}-\frac{∂fG3}{∂x},\frac{∂fG2}{∂x}-\frac{∂fG1}{∂y})$,  (which is to be expanded with the product rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the left, the product $fG$ is still a vector field, so if you know how to calculate curls, go right ahead, since $f$ just scales the components of $G.$

On the right, $\nabla f×G$ is the cross between the gradient of $f$ (a vector by definition), and $G,$ also a vector, both three-dimensional, so the product is defined; also, $f(\nabla × G)$ is just $f,$ a scalar field, times the curl of $G,$ a vector. This is also defined. So you have two vectors on the right summing to the vector on the left.

As for proving, just go component wise; it might be easier working from right to left.

Finally, note that this can be remembered easily by the analogous Leibniz rule in single-variable calculus for differentiating the product of two functions.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand quite a lot of concepts. Editing...just hit enter early

Comment: @Lightsong You're welcome. I'm glad you found my answer helpful.

Comment: I edited the main post, I had understood quite a lot thanks to your answer but I actually am probably missing something basic or just made one operation wrong :P (Btw: I made an answer on your post directly with the question itself since I based what I did on yours, is it common etiquette to do it that way and later on edit the solution above or to just edit the main post?)

Comment: @Lightsong The 1st is right, except for the notation. You write $\partial f_iG_j;$ I think it's better to write $G_j \partial f_i$ instead. As for the 2nd, why don't you expand? Then you'll see it's basically *not* the same as the 1st; each term here is an algebraic sum of terms of the form $f\partial G_i.$ This is different from the corresponding terms $G_j\partial f_i$ in the first. Finally, when you add corresponding terms, you have $$\partial (fG_i)_j$$ in the third expansion. Again, your notation $\partial {fG_i}_j$ is confusing. In general, use brackets to clearly delimit the arguments.

Comment: THANK YOU! Now I got it. I expanded it and indeed it's not the same. I then used the product rule on the left term and they are equal to the sum on the right. We don't use indexes when writing down the terms for some reason so that contributed to mine and your confusion when reading my comment, and incidentally I also found out that even without that way of writing it down I was indeed being confusing so...two birds with the one stone. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just write it out? Let $G=(G_1, G_2, G_3)$. Then
\begin{align}
\nabla \times (fG) &= (\partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3) \times (fG_1, fG_2, fG_3)\\
&= (\partial_2(fG_3) - \partial_3(fG_2), \partial_3(fG_1)-\partial_1(fG_3), \partial_1(fG_2)-\partial_2(fG_1))\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$∇ × (f G) =\sum{\hat{i} \times \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f G)} =\sum{\hat{i}\times ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} G + f  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}G)}= (\sum{\hat{i}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}) \times G + f (\sum{\hat{i}}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}) = ∇f × G + f (∇ × G)$$

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand side is a vector with $i$th component $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(fG_k)$, with implicit summation over the repeated indices $j,\,k$. By the product rule, this splits into $\epsilon_{ijk}(\partial_jf)G_k+f\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jG_k$. The first of these terms is the $i$th component of the vector $(\nabla f)\times G$; the second term is the $i$th component of the vector $f(\nabla\times G)$, where the parentheses indicate multiplication of the vector $\nabla\times G$ by the scalar $f$. Thus $\nabla\times fG=\nabla f\times G+f\nabla\times G$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done much faster with differential forms! The first thing to notice is that for a scalar field $f$ and a vector field $\vec{F}$ there exists corresponding 0 form and one form field respectively. In $R^3$, we can write:

$$ (f \vec{F}) \to f \left(  P dx + Q dy + Rdz\right)= f \alpha$$

Now, taking the curl of the product of scalar field and vector field corresponds to taking the exterior derivative of the form field on the right, hence:

$$ d \left[ (f \alpha) \right] = df \wedge \alpha + (-1)^0 f \wedge d \alpha $$

Now note that following correspondances: $df \to \nabla F$ and $ d \alpha \to \nabla \times \vec{F}$, wedge product of two one forms the cross product, and finally, the wedge product of a 0 form and the exterior derivative of a oneform corresponds to multiplying the curl of the vector field corresponding to that form by the scalar function

$$ (f \vec{F}) \to d( f \vec{F}) =df \wedge \alpha + f \wedge d \alpha \to \nabla f \times \vec{F} + f \nabla \times \vec{F} $$

Hence,

$$ \nabla (f \vec{F}) = \nabla f \times \vec{F} + f \nabla \times \vec{F}$$
Done!

More information in this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nr_o2wnZydk&list=PLB8F2D70E034E9C29&index=16) and in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)